# What do you use for your internal documentation?

Tags: 2007, discussion-board

I've been tasked with creating an internal documentation system that lives within SharePoint. I've considered a wiki for this however the Wiki Library on MOSS is limited to the point of being unusable and despite working for a rather large company the price of Kwizcom's Wiki Plus is overly exorbitant given that we have a load balancing setup (they were unwilling to offer us a farm based license).

What I'm wondering - What other solutions are out there? Are there any MOSS2007 addons for documentation that I may be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use wikis with additional metadata columns added to the library for data capture. You could also use a document library with a content type and a word template associated with it too.

Comment: Have you overcome MOSS's images limitation (having to upload them in a separate list before using them)?

Comment: No, not yet, that's one of the problems with SharePoint wikis.