# Is there an easy way to turn 1300+ individual documents into a Wiki?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, wiki, conversion

Nearly a year ago, I'd asked [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42552/i-need-some-advice-on-creating-a-document-repository/42557#42557). Amazingly, the project is moving forward faster than a speeding snail. Right now, we've got all of the data imported as both Word and HTML docs, 'cause no one's really decided which direction they're going on that for sure, and I did come up with a list that cross-references all the documents to each other as needed. That was an interesting feat.

The idea of Wikis is rearing it's head again, and I've got an idea that I want to float out there for feedback, even if that feedback is "are you out your gourd?"

Luckily, all the documents lived in one directory, and are now in one doc library. We ended up with about 3200 of them. All of the hyperlinks are just `<a href="foo.html">foo</a>` with no path specified. So here's my idea: a quick Powershell script to global replace all the `<a href="` with `[[`, `">foo` with `|foo` `</a>` with `]]`.

If I'm doing my math right, hyperlinks to other documents magically become `[[foo.html|foo]]`. I can then convert to plaintext to strip off the rest of the HTML coding leaving me with a body of documents that are "Wiki-fied" and will *theroetically* link themselves when a link is clicked.

However: it appears that SPWiki creates ASPX files, and it does NOT appear that there's a way to mass copy a bunch of files into the Wiki page library. Does anyone know if there is a way to move these docs into a Wiki en masse? or create a document library that can be CONVERTED to a wiki once everything's there?

Interested to hear thoughts.

Comment: Do you mean that you want all of the documents' contents combined to be inserted into one wiki? That's the only way I can think of translating a document into a wiki page. You may need to write a program to read the contents of each one and insert them into the contents of the destination page if that's the case.

Comment: Right now I have 1300+ inter-hyperlinked (it's a word now!) docs in a document library. My end result is to have 1300+ Wiki pages in a wiki library.

Answer (score 1):

unless you make a utility(application) or a console app to do that for you but requires alot of thinking..... well not that much but requires some code to do what you want to do!

or you can do this:

Created a new wiki page library the way you want it. Now using "Manage Content and Structure" you can moved all items from the old library to the new one that you just made. Once complete you can simply remove the old library ;)

"Manage Content and Structure"

[image]

**Select multiple items**

> On the Site Content and Structure page, any action that you can
> perform on a single item you can perform on multiple items by first
> selecting the items and then selecting an action.
>
> 1.On the Site Content and Structure page, next to Type, click the Select All Items button. Clear the items that you do not want to
> include. To select a single item, select the check box next to the
> item.
>
> 2.Click Actions, and then click the action you want to perform.

**Copy items**

> You can copy entire subsites or lists to another subsite in the site
> collection hierarchy or you can copy individual list items to any
> compatible list. However, it is not possible to use the copy action to
> duplicate a list item in the same list.   After you perform the copy
> action, the site navigation is updated for all navigation components,
> and the site navigation will reflect that the subsites, lists or list
> items are in both locations.
>
> 1.On the Site Content and Structure page, select the item or select multiple items to copy.
>
> 2.Click Actions, and then click Copy.
>
> 3.In the Copy dialog box, select a destination, and then click OK.
>
> 4.The source items are validated to ensure that it is compatible with the destination container. If validation determines: An item is
> compatible, the item will be copied, and the Site Content and
> Structure page will be displayed. An item is not compatible, an error
> message appears, and the item will not be copied.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/work-with-site-content-and-structure-HA010131723.aspx#BM3

Before you do it on the actual library i would recommend that you first make two dummy librarys and test it out with dummy documents to see if it works the way yo want it ;) once your happy you can go ahead!